# SDO_NN the second nearest neighbor

Tags: sql, oracle11g, geospatial

Oracle SQL geometry allows to find the nearest neighbor using

`SDO_NN(neighbors.GEOLOC,p.GEOLOC,'SDO_NUM_RES=1 UNIT = MILE',1) = 'TRUE')`
How to select the second nearest point?